# How to bypass focus from tablepanellayout and move focus to edit box (child of tablepanellayout) directly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a tablepanellayout which has three child control (label, edit box, button).
I have defined access key(alt+somekey) on label.

But when i press access key focus is going to tablepanellayout then to edit box.

My goal is to move focus to edit box directly.

What I tried.

1. tried changing tabindex. didn't work.

   2. thought to write focus handler for tablepanellayout and move foucs to edit control but shifttab won't work.
   3. changed the order of adding child into tablepanellayout (label, editbox, button) no effect.
   4. thought to change the tablepanellayout focus setting but didn't find any property whihc can do this.

How can move fouc to directly to editbox on pressing of access key and bypass focus to tablepanellayout?

EDIT: Screenshot from inpect tool
[image]

Comment: *When I press access key focus is going to TableLayoutPanel then to TextBox.* `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't get focus, just the `TextBox` get focus. But `Enter` event of parents will fire in order.

Comment: Yes thats true. but focus goes to TableLayoutPanel i confirmed it from inpect tool.Please see my edit for screen shot

Comment: It doesn't have nay visual impact. What's the problem? It works the same way for all controls. Put some nested panels on a form and put a `TextBox` in the innermost panel, when you select the `TextBox` even using moues you will see `Enter` even of all panels raise in order.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
As the tab is working fine only problem is with access key hence implemented gotfocus event handler which sets focus to text box.